# How to calculate a new status column runtime in parent table (status logic based on child table) with distinct output

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my sample data:

```
DECLARE @Project TABLE(Id INT, [Name] Varchar(50), ProjectPhase varchar(10), Created datetime);
INSERT INTO @Project Values
(1, 'Project1','I', GETDATE()),
(2, 'Project2','II', GETDATE()),
(3, 'Project3','IV', GETDATE()),
(4, 'Project4','V', GETDATE()),
(5, 'Project5','III', GETDATE()),
(6, 'Project6','II', GETDATE())

--- ProjectId (ForeingKey - Project)
DECLARE @Files TABLE(Id INT, ProjectId INT, Title Varchar(50), Ver Varchar(5), [Status] varchar(20), Created datetime);
INSERT INTO @Files Values
(1, 1, 'Title1','1.0', 'Initiated', GETDATE()),
(2, 1, 'Title1','2.0', 'Rejected', GETDATE()),
(3, 1, 'Title1','3.0', 'Completed', GETDATE()),
(4, 2, 'Title1','1.0', 'InProgress', GETDATE()),
(5, 2, 'Title1','2.0', 'Initiated', GETDATE()),
(6, 2, 'Title1','3.0', 'Approved', GETDATE()),
(7, 2, 'Title1','4.0', 'Completed', GETDATE()),
(8, 2, 'Title1','5.0', 'Completed', GETDATE()),
(9, 3, 'Title1','1.0', 'Completed', GETDATE()),
(10, 3, 'Title1','2.0', 'Completed', GETDATE()),
(11, 3, 'Title1','3.0', 'Completed', GETDATE()),
(12, 4, 'Title1','1.0', 'Approved', GETDATE()),
(13, 4, 'Title1','2.0', 'Approved', GETDATE()),
(14, 5, 'Title1','1.0', 'InProgress', GETDATE()),
(15, 6, 'Title1','1.0', 'Completed', GETDATE()),
(16, 6, 'Title1','2.0', 'Approved', GETDATE()),
(17, 6, 'Title1','3.0', 'Approved', GETDATE()),
(18, 6, 'Title1','4.0', 'Completed', GETDATE())


--Select P.Id, P.[Name], P.ProjectPhase, P.Created
--From @Project p
-- Inner Join @Files f on 
--p.Id = F.ProjectId
```

### **Requirement**

1. Create a new runtime column 'ProjectStatus' in final output considering calculation logic

### **Calculation Logic for ProjectStatus column**

1. If ANY record in @Files table has 'Initiated' Status then ProjectStatus is 'Project Initiated'
2. IF ALL records in @Files table have 'Approved' Status then ProjectStatus is 'Fully Approved'
3. IF ALL records in @Files table have 'Completed' Status then ProjectStatus is 'Live'
4. IF All records in @Files table have 'Approved' AND 'Completed' Status then ProjectStatus is 'Live'
5. IF Any OR All records have status like InProgress, Submitted, OnHold Status then ProjectStatus is 'InProgress'

---

### **Expected Result**

```
DECLARE @ExpectedResult TABLE(Id INT, [Name] Varchar(50),  ProjectPhase varchar(10), ProjectStatus varchar(30), Created datetime);
INSERT INTO @ExpectedResult Values
(1, 'Project1','I', 'Project Initiated',  GETDATE()),
(2, 'Project2','II', 'Project Initiated', GETDATE()),
(3, 'Project3','IV', 'Live', GETDATE()),
(4, 'Project4','V', 'Fully Approved', GETDATE()),
(5, 'Project5','III', 'InProgress', GETDATE()),
(6, 'Project6','II', 'Live', GETDATE())

Select * From @ExpectedResult
```

I am using Microsoft SQL SERVER.

Comment: Also you have tagged 2 different products, MySQL and SQL Server, unless you specifically need a solution for both you should only tag a single product.

Comment: Sorry. I had done with the PIVOT table but it was not an effective considering performance and also complex. it was long solution so not posted... but will keep in mind :). Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sample data.

PFB query achieves the result:

```sql
SELECT p.Id,p.Name, 
CASE WHEN InitiatedStatusCount >= 1 THEN 'Project Initiated' 
    WHEN TotalFilescount = ApprovedStatusCount THEN 'Fully Approved'
    WHEN TotalFilescount = CompletedStatusCount THEN 'Live'
    WHEN TotalFilescount = ApprovedStatusCount + CompletedStatusCount THEN 'Live'
    WHEN InProgressStatusCount >=1 THEN 'In Progress' end as ProjectStatus,
    Getdate() as statusdate
FROM @project as p
inner join (
SELECT f.ProjectId, COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'Initiated' THEN 1 END) As InitiatedStatusCount,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'Approved' THEN 1 END) As ApprovedStatusCount,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'Completed' THEN 1 END) As CompletedStatusCount,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN Status in ('InProgress', 'Submitted', 'OnHold') THEN 1 END) As InProgressStatusCount,
 COUNT(*) AS TotalFilescount
from @Files as f
GROUP BY f.projectId) as f
on p.Id = f.projectid
```

```
+----+----------+-------------------+-------------------------+
| Id |   Name   |   ProjectStatus   |       statusdate        |
+----+----------+-------------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | Project1 | Project Initiated | 2020-07-14 22:06:54.180 |
|  2 | Project2 | Project Initiated | 2020-07-14 22:06:54.180 |
|  3 | Project3 | Live              | 2020-07-14 22:06:54.180 |
|  4 | Project4 | Fully Approved    | 2020-07-14 22:06:54.180 |
|  5 | Project5 | In Progress       | 2020-07-14 22:06:54.180 |
|  6 | Project6 | Live              | 2020-07-14 22:06:54.180 |
+----+----------+-------------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` expressions as following

```
select
  *,
  case 
    when status = 'initiated' then 'Project Initiated'
    when status = 'Approved' then 'Fully Approved'
    else 'In Progress'
  end as ProjectStatus
from Files
order by
  id
```

Comment: I have already tried but that doesn't give me a distinct output after I join both the tables...

Comment: The above query doesn't update ProjectStatus column perfectly as I can see multiple statuses for the same projectId. e.g. "Project Initiated" and "Fully Approved" for ProjectId=2.. Ideally, it should have "Project Initiated" status as one of the column has Initiated status

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a third table with the Status configuration.

```
StatusId, Status, ProjectStatusInizialized, ProjectStatusAproved, ProjectStatusLive, ....
```

Example data (its not complete, but I think you will get the point):

```
1,Inizialized,1,0,0,..   
2,Completed,0,0,0,..  
3,Approved,0,1,0,..  
...
```

Now you can join the project, files and status Tables all togeter and group by your Project data, counting the Files Rows and summing the Projectstatusfields. Now it should be easy to create your when classes where you say if counted files = ProjectStatusInizialized than "Project Inizailied", etc.